# how to run a signed app you've written and installed on oculus quest 2 from the quest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing, oculusquest

I've written an OpenXR app and got it to build and run on my Oculus Quest 2 using Android Studio and a USB cable between my laptop and the quest 2. I've now signed the VulkanDebug built variant of the application. When I click Android Studio's green right arrow button to build and install the app, Android Studio pops up a window telling me that it can't install the app because an app with the same ID is already running and gives me the option to uninstall the existing app before proceeding. I tell it to uninstall the existing app and it proceeds to install the latest version of my app and run it.

So that's great, but what I can't figure out is since I've now installed my app on the Oculus Quest 2, how to I run the installed app from the Quest 2 user interface without getting the laptop involved?

The only way I've found to re-run my app it to fire up Android Studio, attach the Quest 2 to it via the USB cable and click the green arrow again, at which point I to through the uninstall the old/install the new procedure again.

Where in the Oculus Quest GUI should I be able to find my app?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to the folks on the Monado discord server for answering this for me. It's all explained in the short doc at this link:

https://innovate.it.miami.edu/_assets/pdf/tutorial-for-installing-app.pdf

Just skip the stuff about Sidequest on pages 1 through 3, which describe the process of obtaining Sideloaded packages and installing them on your Quest, and go straight to page 4, which describes how to start up the app once its installed.

My app was under "unknown sources" as described in the PDF.